# Changing GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL has no effect

Tags: grub2, color-management

I decommented and edited the two lines in `/etc/default/grub` which are relative to the colors, as follows

```
GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="green/black"
GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-green/green"
```

then I've run `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and reboot. Strangely it seems that only the second line had effect.

On the other hand, when I hit <kbd>C</kbd> on GRUB's main screen and get the console, then I can enter, for instance, `set color_normal=yellow/blue` and `set color_highlight=red/cyan` and verify that both commands had effect (after going back to GRUB's main screen by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

I've also tried to put those two lines just before

```
if [ x$GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL != x ] && [ x$GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT != x ] ; then
    cat << EOF
set menu_color_normal=$GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL
set menu_color_highlight=$GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT

EOF
fi
```

in `/etc/grub.d/00_header`, thinking that `/etc/default/grub` could be overridden by this latter file, but it still has no effect.

[image]